# How to change the shape of the floating action button for bottom tab in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing the bottom tab in flutter and for the middle tab i want the custom shape and design .
Attaching the screenshot for the reference.

[image]

How can i achieve the above design for the bottom tab? Or is there any package which can help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;


Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
          math.pi / 4,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Center(
              child: Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                  -math.pi / 4,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.person_outline,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

here is the result:

[image]